# rsyslog - timestamp setting - log file(imfile)

Tags: redhat, rsyslog

I applied the following setting on the .conf for rsyslog, it can read logs from the file.

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")

input(
    type="imfile" File="/root/loggingFile.log"
    Tag="tag2"
    Severity="notice"
    Facility="local0"
)
```

The logs in the file also come as follows-directly the same, nothing different (like time);

```
trying1
trying2
trying3
...
tryingNew
```

It can read the logs, but every time a new line is written, it reads the whole file from the beginning.
When I make **freshStartTail = on**, even though the new line appears, it does not read at all this time.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the whole `rsyslog.conf`? I have a guess as to what it could be..